# Issue with caching after upgrading to Spring Framework 5.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

After upgrading Spring Framework from 5.1.14.RELEASE to 5.2.6.RELEASE. We have started to get issues during boot.

We have tried JSR-107 (ehcache 3.x) implementation and also using ehcache 2.x but still face the same issue regardless of how we setup our caching solution. Reverting back to 5.1.14.RELEASE then everything is green again, but ofc we want to use 5.2.x.

```
  <cache:annotation-driven/>
  <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="jCacheManager"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="jCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="cacheManagerUri" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
  </bean>
```

We get below stack trace on startup

```
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:471)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:350)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    ... 117 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:572)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:419)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:58)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:205)
    ... 124 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler 9
Exception Details:
  Location:
    se/perra/srs/common/bean/cache/CacheSettingBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$67d53017.<init>()V @9: athrow
  Reason:
    Current frame's flags are not assignable to stack map frame's.
  Current Frame:
    bci: @0
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis }
    stack: { 'java/lang/RuntimeException' }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @9
    flags: { }
    locals: { }
    stack: { 'java/lang/Throwable' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a59 b701 76b8 0038 b1bf bb00 4e5a 5fb7
    0000010: 0051 bf                                
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [0, 9] => handler: 9
    bci [0, 9] => handler: 9
    bci [0, 9] => handler: 10
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@9,{},{Object[#76]})
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@10,Object[#76])
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:571)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:363)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:585)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
```

The application code is straightforward JSR-107 annotations..

```
@CacheResult(cacheName = "setting")
  public Setting getSetting(String component, String key) {
    return jdbcSettingDao.getSetting(component, key);
  }
```

And the ehcache.xml

```
<config
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:jsr107="http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107"
  xmlns="http://www.ehcache.org/v3"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.8.xsd
        http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.8.xsd">

  <service>
    <jsr107:defaults enable-management="false" enable-statistics="true"/>
  </service>

  <cache-template name="medium">
    <expiry>
      <ttl unit="minutes">60</ttl>
    </expiry>
    <heap unit="entries">1000</heap>
  </cache-template>

  <cache alias="setting" uses-template="medium"/>
</config>
```

Comment: Do you have more lines in the stack trace? Something like 'Caused by'? And what are you trying to cache? Can you show the code?

Comment: I've added some more lines of the stack trace and also some application logic. And again when reverting back to 5.1.14.RELEASE everything works fine.

Comment: Can you try recompiling all your code with Spring 5.2.6 dependencies? The VerifyError indicates that some exception's parent class is different at compile time from at run time, which breaks backwards compatibility.

Comment: I found the issue now! 
We are using jersey-spring5 2.30 and that has en explicit dependency towards spring-aop version 5.1.5.RELEASE. 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-spring5/2.30

So I guess they changed compiler version in spring between 5.1 and 5.2 ?

Thanks a lot for your help! :-)